# Is there a way to watch blitz championship currently on chess.com on youtube?

Tags: online-chess, online, online-blitz

Carlsen vs Grischuk: GM Blitz Battle Chess is currently being played on chess.com and being streamed on the chess channel on twitch.

My connection is very slow at the moment and I'm super busy and I'd like to watch previous matches especially the one that Carlsen played the other day. I have a free account on twitch and chess.com. Cess.com doesn't upload everything to youtube.

If they don't upload the video, is there any other way that I can watch the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to go to the Past Broadcasts section on Twitch. I believe there is a newish Twitch feature called Clips that you may want to check out. If someone created a clip of the match, it would save you having to rewatc

Answer (score 2):

The stream from earlier today is available to be viewed [here](https://www.twitch.tv/chess/v/85266999).

There will be another broadcast tomorrow, but that will be a separate stream, with a different link to view (and the link won't be available until tomorrow).